# UITableView and background image shift down after dismissing modalview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a view with a tab bar and a table view in it. At a certain point I call a modal view, and when I dismiss it, the original view seems to stretch or shift down, as the background image is lower and the table view is longer to the point that the last cell goes outside of the frame.

I call the modal view from `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSMutableDictionary *row        = [[[[self.productDetails valueForKey:@"sections"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"rows"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSMutableDictionary *post       = [self.productDetails valueForKey:@"post"];
    if ([[row valueForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"pick"])
    {
        self.xPicker                = nil;
        self.xPicker.options        = nil;
        self.pickerOptions          = nil;
        self.xPicker                = [[[TablePicker alloc] initWithNibName:@"TablePicker" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];
        NSMutableDictionary *newPicker  = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
        [newPicker setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.section] forKey:@"section"];
        [newPicker setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row] forKey:@"row"];
        [newPicker setValue:[row valueForKey:@"options"] forKey:@"options"];
        [newPicker setValue:[row valueForKey:@"value"] forKey:@"value"];
        self.xPicker.options        = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:newPicker];
        self.pickerOptions          = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:newPicker];
        self.xPicker.view.frame     = self.view.bounds;
        [self presentModalViewController:self.xPicker animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Inside the modal view controller, I do some stuff, then fire a notification to let the parent controller know that it's ok to dismiss it. This part doesn't feel right, but I was getting an error occassionally when I had the modal view call:

```
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Anyways, the code block where I dismiss the modal view is as follows:

```
- (void) reloadCell
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    if (self.xPicker.choice != nil)
    {
        NSDictionary *choice        = self.xPicker.choice;
        NSMutableDictionary *row    = [[[[self.productDetails valueForKey:@"sections"] objectAtIndex:[[choice valueForKey:@"section"] intValue]] valueForKey:@"rows"] objectAtIndex:[[choice valueForKey:@"row"] intValue]];
        [row setObject:[choice valueForKey:@"value"] forKey:@"value"];
        [[self.productDetails valueForKey:@"post"] setObject:[choice valueForKey:@"value"] forKey:[row valueForKey:@"key"]];
        Request *xReq               = [[[Request alloc] init] autorelease];
        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(updateOrderFromProductDetails:) toTarget:xReq withObject:[self.productDetails valueForKey:@"post"]];
        self.xPicker                = nil;
    }
}
```

I don't know if it's related, but I found it interesting that when I present this modal controller while the device is in landscape mode, the view goes wonky.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

***Edit:*** After some searching, it appears that both problems are related and have to do with my current view controller being a subview of another view controller, but not through a navigation controller.

As I understand it, my decision to not use a nav controller is confusing my view stack somehow. I had a feeling that would come back to bite me in the butt.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a solution to my problem anywhere.

Comment: There must be something wrong with the frame of the table view. Can you post your whole implementation (.m) file?

Comment: Do you have any navigation controllers or toolbars?

Comment: So when you call [myTableView reloadData] the frame becomes messed up (meaning it extends past the bottom of your content view)?

Comment: @Dylan It seems you were on the right track. I retested it, and I found that it was resizing, and was also shifting the background down. I'm not sure why how I missed it before, but I updated my question with more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have one solution to this problem.

Instead of having my current view controller call `presentModalViewController`, I call it from the appDelegate `tabBarController` like so:

```
[[(myAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] tabBarController] presentModalViewController:self.myModalViewController animated:YES];
```

This still feels a bit hacky, but it solves both problems of

1) resizing when the modal view is dismissed

2) the modal view being unable to pop up in landscape mode

I hope this can help someone else out there in this cruel Apple world.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a nib associated with the views - go into the nib for each view and set the following attributes on the main view in each nib:

status bar: unspecified

top bar: unspecified

bottom bar: unspecified

Then in the size:
x:0,y:0,W:320,H480

Back in the code after you've allocated each view also set the 'wantsFullScreenLayout' property to TRUE on each view.

Edit: explanation (? maybe ? :-))

If you have a status bar specified in the nib then the uikit automatically adjusts your views to cater for the status bar (and you'll see that your view yorigin is 0 and height is 460 in the nib) but if you look at the offset/height in the frame in your viewDidAppear method its been set to 20/460 to cater for the status bar.

For some reason presenting modal view controllers seems to mess with this and adjust for the status bar again, shifting your view down another 20.  Setting status bar to unspecified and setting wantsFullScreen layout stops uikit messing with your frame and gives you control (hence setting height to 480 in the nib sizing).

You will also need to move all of your view elements down by 20 to cater for the status bar height in the 480 height view.

Comment: Sorry if I'm just being ignorant, but I don't see how this would provide a solution.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but that didn't change anything. It also feels like a cover up of some more serious underlying problem, which is what I'd really like to deal with.

Answer (score -1):

When your main view comes back, try adding:

`[myTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,411)];`.

Comment: Thanks, but that solution is a bit too static. It's been my experience that resizing to exact dimensions tends to cause unwanted surprises. I'm looking for a solution that would prevent the shifting in the first place.